# uWSGI harakiri with Django does not always work

Tags: python, django, linux, multithreading, uwsgi

I have a Django application that's run on uWSGI.

I have the following uWSGI settings:

```
master = true
processes = 8

enable-threads = true
threads = 25
harakiri = 30
harakiri-verbose = true
```

When I connect to this server by more than 30 seconds, the process should be killed. I verified the process termination by monitoring the log file. The long process was done by putting the thread to sleep (time.sleep(200)) in Django.

What confuses me is that even though I've already seen from the log that the process has been terminated, sometimes, it still continue running (after the sleep). My expectation is that if the process has been running more than 30 seconds, it should be killed and never continue.

Am I missing some details? or implementing it incorrectly?
Is putting the thread to sleep somehow is the same as killing the thread and on wake up time, create a new thread with different id? Thus, killing the thread by uWSGI will not impact the thread on Django.

Thanks in advance.